# How to upload image in ruby app folder and insert url in database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> Controller
>
> ## Save the object

How to Use This Controller to insert image in any folder and image url store in database
`def create_json`

```
    @user = User.new(userFirstName: params[:userFirstName], userLastName: params[:userLastName], userEmail: params[:userEmail], password: encrypted_password, userImage: params[:userImage])
if @user.save       #if save succeeds, redirect to the index action
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', id: User.last.id)
        else
    #if not succeeds, redirect to the index action  
        redirect_to(:action => 'new')
        end end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User(Model) mount_uploader :userImage, AvatarUploader`

```
UsersController -> @user = User.new(user_params)
                    if @user.save
                     redirect_to(:action => 'show', id: User.last.id)
                    else
                    render :json => data_hash2, :content_type => 'application/json' 
                    end



class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
storage :file
def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png) 
    end  end
```

> If You Using Web Service

```
<form action="http://ruby/controllername/create" lass="new_user" id="new_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

**View following method for uploading files to app/assets/images/people_profile_images folder**

First upload Image like this:

```
@user =User.new(user_params)
  #this will create user form paramaters given
uploaded_file = params[:user][:photo]
#this will add uploaded image or file in uplaoded_fie
if (uploaded_file)
  File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'images/people_profile_images', uploaded_file.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_file.read)
    @user.photo = "/assets/people_profile_images/"+uploaded_file.original_filename
  end
else
  @user.photo = "/assets/people_profile_images/default_avatar.png"
end
```

then save user

```
@user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an approach that can cover both: image uploading and then saving the url on the database.

You can do one or the other:

1) Use a gem called paperclip that helps upload image files.

See this links:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#ruby-and-rails

https://teamtreehouse.com/library/image-uploads-in-ruby-on-rails-41 (paperclip, carrierwave, and dragonfly)

I have used paperclip and it has worked well for me.

OR:

2) Include it as an additional field on your filename.html.erb for your image_url

One caveat, of using this though is that this can be changed and you have no control of the image that might show on your site. Thus, the image_url should be from a reputable CDN or at least from a reputable user uploading to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column url:string in your model. Add it as a hidden field in your form. Set its value to the same as your remote_url using .js

var urladdy = input.remoteurl.val()

input.url.val(urladdy)

This will upload image with carrier wave and also save its url as string.